# Job of meta_key meta_value fields in database tables

Tags: post-meta, user-meta, meta-value

I'm researching the structure of WordPress database and there is something that really get me confuesd.
Could someone please explain, what is the *exact* job of `meta_key` and `meta_value` fields in `wp_commentmeta`, `wp_postmeta`, `wp_usermeta` tables? What is the job of these tables anyway?

I did read the Database Description in the Codex, but still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of them as array key/value pairs (kinda). These tables are used to store additional data about particular posts, comments, or users. The `meta_key` is the name by which the `meta_value` is retrieved, plus you have associations with particular posts, comments, or users by means of IDs. As far as ***structure*** goes, that is about it. These are "extra info" tables. You can even add to them via the backend. `*_postmeta` is where the [custom fields are stored](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

WordPress stores, and plugins and themes can store, a wide variety or information there. Some of those tables have critical information, like role/capability data, but you may also have relatively trivial data like someone's Jabber handle (Is that even around anymore?), or a favorite color.

Comment: First Thank you for your concern :)
and what is the difference of these tables and the wp_comments or wp_users... ? aren't they enough to store the data wp needs?

Comment: `wp_comments`, `wp_posts`, and `wp_users` store a very particular collection of ***specific*** information. If you want to store something that isn't in that specific set you need to put it elsewhere, or keep adding column after column to table. WordPress does the former (and I approve :) ).

Comment: ow now i get it ! thanks a lot. you were a great help :)